# How to send long message without parts - smpplib python

Tags: python, smpp

How to send long message without parts using python-smpplib, i want to send long message in one part.

```
pdu = client.send_message(
        source_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
        source_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
        source_addr=source,
        dest_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
        dest_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
        destination_addr=dest,
        short_message=message,
        data_coding=encoding_flag,
        registered_delivery=True
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Via SMPP you can send long message in one part(one submit) only by using the payload optional parameter(in this case the short_message parameter should be empty), and only if your SMPP provider allows it (not all providers do).

Otherwise, your only option is to split the long message in multiple parts(taking into consideration the encoding)